# Generators for prime ideal lifted from basis of cotangent subspace in a complex variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $X$ be a complex, smooth, projective variety. Let $x$ be a (closed) point, $A=\text{Spec}R$ an affine chart for $x$ and $V\subseteq T_x^*X=\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2$ a vector subspace, where $\mathfrak{m}\subseteq R$ is a maximal ideal naturally associated to $x$. If I'm given a basis $v_1,\dots,v_r$ of $V$, how can I lift them to $p_1,\dots,p_r\in R$ so that the ideal $I=\langle p_1,\dots,p_r\rangle\subseteq\mathfrak{m}$ is prime? (lift means that $v_i\equiv p_i\mod \mathfrak{m}^2$).

NOTE: I use $X$ and $x$ instead of just starting with a f.g. $\mathbb{C}$-algebra $R$ and maximal $\mathfrak{m}$ such that $R_\mathfrak{m}$ is a regular local ring because my geometric intuition says there should (obviously?) be some (actually, infinitely many) irreducible algebraic variety $V(I)$ defined as the intersection of $r$ codimension 1 varieties that are "orthogonal" to the cotangent vectors $v_1,\dots,v_r$ but I'm still not good using Nakayama, Krull and other tools from commutative algebra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The truth is, that this is not possible in general, even for $V=\mathfrak m/\mathfrak m^2$. Let $R$ be a Dedekind domain with non-trivial class group and $\mathfrak m$ a non-principal maximal ideal. Then a basis of $V=\mathfrak m/\mathfrak m^2$ consists of only one element, but a non-zero element of $\mathfrak m$ cannot generate a prime ideal, since there are no prime ideals between $\mathfrak m$ and $0$.

Comment: Dear MooS, I really like this answer! So to translate this into geometry language (like in the OP's question), we should look at a smooth projective curve with an open affine chart on which the Picard group is non-trivial, such that the divisor class of our chosen point is not principal within this open affine? For example, an elliptic curve?

Comment: Yes, for instance the open affine chart $y^3=x^2$ is a counter example.

Comment: $y^3 = x^2$ isn't smooth, but unless I'm being stupid (and my brain isn't working today) I believe that any smooth $y^2 = x(x-1)(x-\alpha)$ will do. (Because if a point $p$ is principal on this open chart, then $p-p_\infty$ would need to be principal on the entire projective curve, and it isn't, by Riemann-Roch.) Anyway, I like this answer very much!

Comment: Yes you are of course right, $k[x,y]/(y^3-x^2)$ is not a Dedekind domain. But luckily, as you pointed out, there are plenty of complex affine smooth curves whose coordinate rings are Dedekind domains with non-trivial class group.

Comment: Thanks - I learnt something today! :)

Comment: Thanks MooS, an answer that is both great and simple. Now, just one thing, in the same setting, if I am given $p_1,\dots,p_r$ with $p_i\equiv v_i\mod\mathfrak{m}^2$, can I get a prime ideal $J$ with $\langle p_1,\dots,p_r\rangle\subseteq J\subseteq\mathfrak{m}$ such that $J/\mathfrak{m}^2=V$? At least this must be true! (in your example we would have $J=\mathfrak{m}$)

Comment: $J/\mathfrak m^2$ makes no sense for a prime ideal properpy contained in $\mathfrak m $.

Comment: I meant that $\pi(J)=V\subseteq\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2$ for the map of $R$-modules $\pi:\mathfrak{m}\to\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2$

Comment: So you are basically asking whether there is a prime ideal between $\langle p_1, \dotsc, p_r \rangle$ and $\langle p_1, \dotsc, p_r \rangle + \mathfrak m^2$. Gotta think about that.