# Associating a prime ideal to a cotangent subspace in a complex variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

This is a weakened alternative to a question that was answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2265211/generators-for-prime-ideal-lifted-from-basis-of-cotangent-subspace-in-a-complex)

Let $X$ be a complex, smooth, projective variety. Let $x$ be a (closed) point, $A=\text{Spec}R$ an affine chart for $x$ and $V\subseteq T_x^*X=\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2$ a vector subspace, where $\mathfrak{m}\subseteq R$ is a maximal ideal naturally associated to $x$.

If I'm given a **basis** $v_1,\dots,v_r$ of $V$ and an ideal $I=\langle p_1,\dots,p_r\rangle$ generated by representatives $p_i\in \mathfrak{m}$ of the basis (i.e. $v_i\equiv p_i\mod\mathfrak{m}^2$), can I find a **prime** ideal $J$, such that $I\subseteq J\subseteq \mathfrak{m}$ and $J\mod\mathfrak{m}^2=V$?
 **Observation**: as observed by MooS these two conditions are equivalent to having a prime $J$ between $I$ and $I+\mathfrak{m}^2$.

If necessary, the $p1,\dots,p_r$ may be assumed irreducible.

Comment: I am sorry. I would have to think some more. Both of my previous answers are wrong. So I deleted them.

Comment: No problem, thanks for all the help. Since you erased your answer to my original question I now reformulated the question so that the main point (having a basis) is clear in the main part of the question and not in an updated note below.

Comment: You should add the observation that the statement is equivalent to the existence of a prime between $I$ and $I+\mathfrak m^2$.

Comment: Thanks for the observation, I added it to the question

Comment: Why not take $J=\mathfrak{m}$, which is the only possibility?

Comment: @Mohan If $J=\mathfrak{m}$ then $J \mod \mathfrak{m}^2$ is the whole cotangent space. But $V$ may be strictly smaller subspace. I suppose geometrically the question is as follows. Given a bunch of tangent vectors at a point $x$ can one always find a subvariety (containing $x$) such that its tangent space is the span of our chosen tangent vectors.

Comment: As I said, that is the only possibility. Any prime ideal containing $\mathfrak{m}^2$ must be $\mathfrak{m}$.

Comment: Yes but the OP is not requiring $\mathfrak{p}$ to contain $\mathfrak{m}^2$.